# What does the intersection of curves on a contour plot signify?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I understand that shorter distance between curves indicates steeper slope. Does the intersection of curves indicate infinite slope?

Comment: a bit off topic, but on relief maps it could mean that you have an overhanging cliff.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Consider $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and the level curve $f(x,y)=0$. It is formed by the two straight lines $y=\pm x$, that cut at $(0,0)$; the slopes of the lines are $\pm1$. What is happening is that $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$. This implies that you cannot apply the implicit function theorem and represent the lever curve as $y=y(x)$ or as $x=x(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Not so in general. The as projected profile slopes could be even zero.

Intersecting lines on contour plots are level curves around saddle points of negative Gauss curvature surfaces. There are two directions that are horizontal, roughly asymptotic, depending on how the cutting plane is aspect ed to the topography. *Col* points in mountaineering are an example.

A reference can be made to Dupin's indicatrices.

Level curves appear as concentric ovals  around mountain/valley = peaky/pit  features.

Answer (score 0):

In the neighborhood of a  point ${\bf p}\in{\rm dom}(f)\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ where $\nabla f({\bf p})\ne{\bf 0}$ the level lines of $f$ look like a family of parallel lines. It follows that the phenomenon you describe can only occur at points ${\bf p}$ where $\nabla f({\bf p})={\bf 0}$. Such points are called *critical points* of $f$. The exact  level lines portrait near such a point depends on the higher partial derivatives of $f$. It is comparatively easy to describe when  ${\bf p}$ is a so-called *regular critical point*. This means that $$\det\left[{\partial^2 f\over\partial x_i\partial x_k}\right]_{\bf p}\ne0\ .$$